# VMWare: Linux host doesn't get NAT connection from Windows Host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware, nat

I've been trying the last couple of days to get NAT networking to work.

I am running VMWare workstation on Windows 7, and installed an Ubuntu image. The image starts up fine, but the vm does not get an IP address. The vm is setup to use NAT networking, and this has DHCP enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around a lot, I finally stumbled upon a thread on the VMWare forums (https://communities.vmware.com/thread/494261) which has the title "Can't get VMware NAT Service running".

I realized that the VMWare NAT depends on a Windows service that has to run. So I went to the 
Services settings of Windows, and sure enough, the "VMWare NAT Service" was set to manual. I started it and set it to start automatically, and networking started to work in my vm.